# Why didn't Harry recognize Dumbledore's voice?

Tags: harry-potter

In Order of the Phoenix, Petunia got a Howler which shouted Remember My Last!

We eventually learn that Dumbledore sent the Howler.
Why didn't Harry recognize his voice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An awful voice filled the kitchen, echoing in the confined space, issuing from the burning letter on the table. (*OotP*)

Clearly, Dumbledore had somehow magicked his voice for most dramatic effect (although it's possible that this was merely a standard effect of the Howler that was left un-opened for too long - canon isn't too clear), which is why Harry didn't recognize the voice.

---

Please note that the "standard effect" may be plausible - Mrs Weasley's Howler in *CS* was described thusly:

> He thought for a moment it had exploded; **a roar of sound filled the huge Hall, shaking dust from the ceiling**.
>   ...
>   **Mrs Weasley's yells, a hundred times louder than usual, made the plates and spoons rattle on the table, and echoed deafeningly off the stone walls**.

When a voice is raised to a certain amount of decibels, it becomes harder to figure out if it's a familiar voice.

Comment: Also could add that Harry had never heard Albus yell, so he had no point of reference. Also, he did think it was a familiar voice, just not exactly who.